# Android WiFI is working fine from command line, but not working from GUI

Tags: android, bluetooth, linux-device-driver, android-wifi, wifi

I am using Android JB 4.1.1 in my custom board.
I am using TI WL1283 for wifi and bluetooth support with Samsung Exynos host processor.
in my board, wifi is working fine from command line. i am able to associate with AP and ping the external IP.
but when i try to turn on wifi from GUI ,it's not turning on.

what can be the problem?
what is the flow of Android when we try to turn on wifi from GUI?
can anyone provide the links to good wifi and bluetooth driver programming tutorials?

Thanks and Best regards,
Jags Gediya

Comment: can you show GUI codes ?

Comment: Hi Shivan, thanks for reply. I have android SDK for JB 4.1.1. my work is related to linux and device driver so i dont know any thing about android programming. i dont know in that SDK where is the code for android GUI. I have provided HAL support for my wifi module and wpa_supplicant inside android.

Comment: kill the running supplicant, place your firmware and host driver in appropriate folders(normally /system/vendor/firmware/ )